# IOS: NSKnownKeysDictionary1 error

Tags: ios, nsmanagedobject

I have an object selectedActivity defined as follows:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) Activities *selectedActivity;
```

At the point I need to work with it logs out as:

```
{
    actname = "Running";
    aid = 23;
}
```

The Activities object is an NSManaged object and its .h file looks like this.

```
@interface Activities : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * actname;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * aid;
@end
```

I am trying to place one of the object properties in a variable to work with it using the following:

```
 NSNumber *aid = _selectedActivity.aid;
```

However, the above line gives the following error message:

```
[NSKnownKeysDictionary1 aid]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x147842fb0
```

Can anyone explain this error and how to fix it?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Update:
setting of selected activity

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

     _selectedActivity =([_activities objectAtIndex:row]);
    NSLog(@"selectedActivity in pickerview%@",_selectedActivity);
}
//activities in .h file
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *activities;
//setting of activities
 self.activities= [self getActivities];

//method that gets activities
- (id) getActivities{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Activities"];
     NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"created" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sort]];
    NSError *error      = nil;
    self.managedObjectContext = [Model sharedInstance].managedObjectContext;

    NSArray *results    = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                   error:&error];
      NSMutableArray *mutableresults = [results mutableCopy];
    [mutableresults removeObjectIdenticalTo:[NSNull null]];

    return mutableresults; 
}
```

Comment: Show the code where you assign a value to `selectedActivity`.  Apparently it's a dictionary and not an instance of `Activities`

Answer (score 0):

The results are coming as a dictionary.

**instead of** the usual `NSManagedObject`-style value retrieval:

*Objective-C*

`NSString *actname = _selectedActivity.actname;
NSNumber *aid = _selectedActivity.aid;`

*Swift*

`let actname:String = _selectedActivity.actname
let aid:Int = _selectedActivity.aid`

**Use** the `NSDictionary`-style value retrieval, like so:

*Objective-C*:

`NSString *actname = [_selectedActivity valueForKey:@"actname"];
NSNumber *aid = [[_selectedActivity valueForKey:@"aid"] intValue];`

*Swift (tested as of 3.0.1)*

`_selectedActivity(forKey: "actname") as! String
_selectedActivity.value(forKey: "aid") as! Int`